# Extract locally stored .blob file

Tags: javascript

Working on a birthday present for a friend i obtained an ipa file and unzipped it only to find the picture assets ive been looking for packed inside a .blob file. Looking at the hex representation of that file i seems to contain the images as .pvr files just packed behind each other.

Do you know any way to extract those .pvr files from a .blob file?
Every help is appreciated!

Comment: Why "Azure" tag?

Comment: Because azure cloud stores data as blobs and why im not sure if this is connected it might be possible

Comment: I have no idea what a `.blob` extension represents, but... it's unrelated to Azure (that is, it's not specific to Azure; Azure blobs are stored objects, regardless of file type/extension/name). This seems like a question best suited for the person or company who provided the `.ipa` file to you. Seems off-topic here though, as it's not related to programming.

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks, the best option seems to manually split up that file